# Update Queryset of Model Choice Filter based on value of other filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

**I know that we can modify a django filter in its init method and we can define custom filter functions for filtering the queryset.**

I have a **model choice filter** which fetches cities from the db. The cities contain different values for example: Aachen, Achen (Kreis) etc.

```
self.filters["city"] = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
            queryset=City.objects.exclude(name__contains="Kreis").order_by("name")
        )
```

I have a **Boolean Filter** named include_kreis

```
self.filters["include_kreis"] = BooleanFilter(
            field_name="city", widget=forms.CheckboxInput, method=self.kreis_custom_filter, label="Include Kreis"
        )
```

As you can see that initially, I have excluded Kreis values and the checkbox is unchecked.

My **custom function** for include_kreis filter is:

```
def kreis_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    if value == False:
        return queryset.exclude(city__name__contains="Kreis")
    else:
        return queryset.all()
```

I am adding the cities with Kreis in its name to the queryset based on the value of Bool filter.

**What I want is to also modify the values in the model choice filter City.**

**Something like this:**

```
self.filters["city"].queryset = City.objects.all().order_by("name")
```

I tried writing the above line in the custom filter function "include_kreis" in else statement but the dropdown on the frontend **doesn't update** the values.

**FAILED ATTEMPT:**

```
def kreis_custom_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    if value == False:
        return queryset.exclude(city__name__contains="Kreis")
    else:
        self.filters["city"].queryset = City.objects.all().order_by("name")
        return queryset.all()
```

A way to do this can be sending an ajax request and repopulate the Dropdown but that is inefficient as I have other filters and javascript event handlers so AJAX way is something which I can not go.

Is there a way to update the queryset of ModelChoice filter I have in the custom filter function or does DJANGO does not allow it?

Also if it is possible to add an if statement in init and check for the current value of the bool filter and then: define the filter with different querysets that is also something which is acceptable.

Something like in **init**:

```
def __init__(self, *args, result_type=None, **kwargs):
    super(Evaluation_filter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.filters["include_kreis"] = BooleanFilter(
        field_name="city", widget=forms.CheckboxInput, method=self.kreis_custom_filter, label="Include Kreis"
    )
    if value of bool filter == on:
      self.filters["city"] = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
         queryset=City.objects.all().order_by("name")
      )

    else:
      self.filters["city"] = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
         queryset=City.objects.exclude(name__contains="Kreis").order_by("name")
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured out the solution:

I **can add an if statement in init method based** on the current REQUEST. I noticed that in *args, the whole request was being sent.

The solution:

```
def __init__(self, *args, result_type=None, **kwargs):
    super(Evaluation_filter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.filters["include_kreis"] = BooleanFilter(
        field_name="city", widget=forms.CheckboxInput, method=self.kreis_custom_filter, label="Include Kreis"
    )
    #evaluate if the checkbox is checked
    if args[0] and args[0].get("include_kreis"):
        city_queryset = City.objects.all().order_by("name")
    else:
        city_queryset = City.objects.exclude(name__contains="Kreis").order_by("name")

    self.filters["city"] = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=city_queryset)
```

`args[0]` **is the request in the form of a dictionary.**

Then I have to get the current value of include_kreis from that.

**Because it is a boolean filter, it will only be populated in the request if it is checked/selected** hence I use `args[0].get()`

Then based on the if statement, I can populate values for the city dropdown.

If the checkbox is *selected*, include all the cities
***Otherwise*** exclude 'Kreis'